# Function variable representing init

Tags: go, function-pointers, init

In Go, you can define multiple `init` functions in a given package, all of which will be run prior to execution in unspecified order. One consequence of having multiples of such functions is that it's impossible to call or identify them in normal code. For example, the following will not compile:

```
func main() {
    fmt.Println(init)
}
func init() { }
```

(see [here](http://play.golang.org/p/oDw3ymzduF) for a Go playground example)
My question is - what advantage does being able to have multiple init functions give, and if there *weren't* multiple init functions, would we be able to reference or call init functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Advantage of being able to have multiple `init` functions is IMO mainly that it improves readability by locality: You can write the initialization function next to the stuff being initialized and not remotely if you would have to centralize all the `init` functions to one. Which, BTW, could be then even in a different source file.

Taking a function pointer of the hypothetical per-package-single `init` function would be probably prohibited as well. The reason is that having such pointer would allow, in some cases, to call the `init` function "out of order", ie. *before* running its dependencies - other `init` functions in other packages. That would break certain [guarantees](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Program_execution).

Comment: Ah, that's a good point about being able to call init out-of-order in other packages (although it wouldn't actually be a problem in practice since init isn't exported).

Comment: Also, not being able to reference `init` excludes recursion as a factor, which simplifies the matter even further.